# I used Exoplayer to play video in android application, but can't show result

Tags: android, xml, video, android-videoview, exoplayer

I used Exoplayer to play video in android application, but can't show result. Please see the code and help me on this issue

## My xml file is

**video.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
xmlns:card_view="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:orientation="vertical">

<android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout
    android:id="@+id/appbar"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:elevation="4dp"
    android:theme="@style/AppTheme.AppBarOverlay">

    <include layout="@layout/toolbar" />
</android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout>

<android.support.v4.widget.NestedScrollView
    android:id="@+id/nested"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    App: layout_behavior="@string/appbar_scrolling_view_behavior">

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:clipToPadding="false"
        android:orientation="vertical">

        <android.support.v7.widget.CardView
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:clipToPadding="false"
            card_view:cardElevation="4dp">

                <LinearLayout
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:orientation="vertical">

                    <LinearLayout
                        android:layout_width="match_parent"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:orientation="vertical">
                       <com.google.android.exoplayer2.ui.SimpleExoPlayerView
                            android:id="@+id/videoView1"
                            android:layout_width="match_parent"
                            android:layout_height="match_parent" />

                    </LinearLayout>

                    <LinearLayout
                        android:layout_width="match_parent"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:gravity="center_vertical"
                        android:orientation="horizontal"
                        android:padding="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin">

                        <LinearLayout
                            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                            android:gravity="center_vertical"
                            android:orientation="horizontal">

                       <LinearLayout
                                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                                android:orientation="vertical"
                   android:paddingStart="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin">

                                <TextView
                                    android:id="@+id/teacher_name"
                                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                                    android:text="Teacher Name"
                                    android:textStyle="bold" />

                                <TextView
                                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                                    android:text="devalyaonline.com"
                                    android:textAppearance="@android:style/TextAppearance.Small" />

                            </LinearLayout>

                        </LinearLayout>

                    </LinearLayout>

                    <LinearLayout
                        android:layout_width="match_parent"
                        android:layout_height="?attr/actionBarSize"
                        android:background="@color/colorButtonDisabled"
                        android:gravity="center_vertical">

                        <TextView
                            android:id="@+id/count_comment"
                            android:layout_width="match_parent"
                            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                            android:layout_marginStart="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
                            android:text="0 comment"
                            android:textAppearance="@android:style/TextAppearance.Medium" />
                    </LinearLayout>

                    <android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView
                        android:id="@+id/comment_recycler_view"
                        android:layout_width="match_parent"
                        android:layout_height="match_parent"
                        android:clickable="true"
                        android:scrollbars="vertical"
                        android:stateListAnimator="@android:anim/fade_in" />

                </LinearLayout>
        </android.support.v7.widget.CardView>

    </LinearLayout>
</android.support.v4.widget.NestedScrollView>

</LinearLayout>
```

## My Activity class file

**Video.java**

```
public class Video extends AppCompatActivity {
 SimpleExoPlayerView videoView;

 @Override
  protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_video);

    Toolbar toolbar = (Toolbar) findViewById(R.id.toolbar);
    setSupportActionBar(toolbar);

    getSupportActionBar().setDisplayHomeAsUpEnabled(true);

    videoView = (SimpleExoPlayerView) findViewById(R.id.videoView1);

    CallVideo();

}

public void CallVideo() {

 Intent get_details = getIntent();
        final int id = Integer.parseInt(get_details.getStringExtra("id"));
   final String video_url = get_details.getStringExtra("video_url");

 sessionManager = new SessionManager(getApplicationContext());

        // Get data from Stored value
        HashMap<String, String> get_token = sessionManager.getUserDetails();
        // Get Token
        String token = get_token.get(SessionManager.KEY_TOKEN);
        String username = get_token.get(SessionManager.KEY_FULL_NAME);

         // 1. Create a default TrackSelector

        BandwidthMeter bandwidthMeter = new DefaultBandwidthMeter();
        TrackSelection.Factory videoTrackSelectionFactory = new AdaptiveTrackSelection.Factory(bandwidthMeter);
        TrackSelector trackSelector = new DefaultTrackSelector(videoTrackSelectionFactory);

        // 2. Create the player

        final SimpleExoPlayer player = ExoPlayerFactory.newSimpleInstance(getApplicationContext(), trackSelector);

        ApiInterface apiService = ApiClient.createClient(ApiInterface.class);

        String video_base_Url = "https://api.vimeo.com/videos/" + video_url;
        final String Video_Token = "Bearer My_Video_Token";

        Call<Videos> video_Call = apiService.getVideo(video_base_Url, Video_Token);

     video_Call.enqueue(new Callback<Videos>() {
            @Override
            public void onResponse(Call<Videos> call, Response<Videos> response) {


                Videos o = response.body();
                String uriPath = o.getUri();
                Uri videouri = Uri.parse(uriPath);


                // Bind the player to the view.
                videoView.setPlayer(player);

                // Measures bandwidth during playback. Can be null if not required.

                DefaultBandwidthMeter bandwidthMeter = new DefaultBandwidthMeter();

                // Produces DataSource instances through which media data is loaded.

                DataSource.Factory dataSourceFactory = new DefaultDataSourceFactory(getApplicationContext(),
                        Util.getUserAgent(getApplicationContext(), "DevalyaAndroidApp"), bandwidthMeter);

                // Produces Extractor instances for parsing the media data.

                ExtractorsFactory extractorsFactory = new DefaultExtractorsFactory();

                // This is the MediaSource representing the media to be played.

                MediaSource videoSource = new ExtractorMediaSource(videouri,
                        dataSourceFactory, extractorsFactory, null, null);

                // Prepare the player with the source.
                player.prepare(videoSource);
                player.setPlayWhenReady(true);
                player.release();


  }

            @Override
            public void onFailure(Call<Videos> call, Throwable t) {

            }
        });

  }

 }
```

## And getting this Output

[image: Not showing the video]

Answer (score 0):

It seems that you release the player just after asking to play. Implements listeners to release the payer when the video stopped and that you don't need the player any more.
https://google.github.io/ExoPlayer/doc/reference/com/google/android/exoplayer2/ExoPlayer.EventListener.html

Answer (score 0):

Remove `player.release();` from that code and add it to another method for when you want to stop the player. As you're calling `player.release();` right after `player.setPlayWhenReady(true);`, you are essentially stopping the video player.